# Need help with writing a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file on Windows which gets one argument: a zip file name that was created with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

This file contains a single MySQL backup file inside, say `backup.sql`.

I would like to restore the database given this zip file.

So, first I extract it to a temporary directory like this:

```
path_to_7zip\7z e "%~1" -otemp_dir
```

And now is my question: How could I know the name of the extracted file (i.e. `backup.sql`) ?

I would like to write something like this:

```
path_to_mysql\mysql < extracted_file_name
```

(where `extracted_file_name` should be `backup.sql`)

What should I write instead of `extracted_file_name` if I don't know the file name that is inside the zip file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the file in an empty directory, where you could be sure that it's the only present file. Then you could use the for instruction to gather such name in a variable and use it as you prefer.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /b *.sql') DO path_to_mysql\mysql < %%F
```

Notice that, if there's more than one SQL file in the archive, all of them will be processed. I think this could be a bonus, but it is undesirable I think you could simply jump out of the `FOR` with a `GOTO`.

---

**Edit**: using *only* the `/F` form of `FOR` I forgot that the "normal" `FOR` does already the job we need.

```
FOR %%F IN (*.sql) DO path_to_mysql\mysql < %%F
```

Notice that all this stuff works only if the current directory is the extraction directory, otherwise you have to change the expressions in the parentheses accordingly.

Bonus links: reference for `FOR` and `FOR /F` - the only commands that do something useful in batch - and that obviously have an impossible syntax. :D

Comment: How should I gather the name in a variable ?

Comment: If the temp directory was initially empty, just use the 'for' command to execute the mysql command over every file in that directory. I don't know the exact syntax, but it's something like `for /f %s in (%tempdir/*) do mysql < %s`.

Comment: Added examples, see original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think 7z has an “`l`” command to list contents of an archive. pipe this output to mysql.

Comment: `l` option is nice but it prints a lot of information besides the file name itself. Are you sure I can pipe all this output to `mysql`?

Comment: No, of course you need to parse it or to find proper options. Isn't 7z command line documented?

Comment: If you need to parse we're back to square one, since we need to use FOR /F anyway.